# Do free TLD's affect SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines

Does a free top level domain such as `.tk` or `.ga` affect your websites SEO?

If it does:

1. Why does it affect SEO?
2. How does it affect SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Country code top-level domains (ccTLD's) such as `.tk` (Tokelau, New Zealand) and `.ga` (Gabon) have extra weight in their own country's search engine (like `google.tk` and `google.ga` for instance) but that is as far as it goes.

That being said however, **some ccTLD are considered gTLD (generic) by Google**, `.tk` being one of them as can be seen under the 'More about domain determination' section [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en&rd=1) (thanks to [Stephen in the comments](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93866/do-free-tlds-affect-seo/93870?noredirect=1#comment117064_93870)). ccTLD's are an extra signal for Google to perceive the site as likely being more relevant to users in those regions/countries.

Google's John Mueller [said this on the matter](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html) just in July 2015.

> Q: What about real ccTLDs (country code top-level domains) : will
>   Google favour ccTLDs (like `.uk`, `.ae`, etc.) as a local domain for people
>   searching in those countries?
>
> A: By default, most ccTLDs (with [exceptions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922)) result in Google using these to geotarget the website; it tells us that the website is probably more relevant in the appropriate country. Again, see our help centre for more information on
>   [multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192).

Comment: Google [considers `.tk` to be a generic top level domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en&rd=1).    Your answer is not correct for `.tk`.   Google would allow your to target a `.tk` site worldwide.   `.ga` is not on Google's list of generic top level domains, so your answer is correct for it.

Comment: I had to look up .tk myself as I was not familiar with it but I went by [Wikipedia that labels it a ccTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk).

Comment: It is a country code domain, but Google treats it as generic for SEO.   If you click on "More about domain determination" on https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en&rd=1 it has a list of country code domains that it treats as generic because they are used around the world.

Comment: I see now, useful to know, thanks for clarifying Stephen. I edited the answer to include your correction.

Answer (score -2):

1) It doesn't.

2) It doesn't

Why should it? Search engines care about content alone.

Comment: Paying for a domain name is a minimal signal that you are not a spammer.   Paid domains, especially those with multi-year registrations are more likely to be trusted quickly by search engines.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller At a minimum but you do have a point. They will be trusted "quicker", not "quickly". But let's make a test to the extreme. If SO was on a free host, would that matter in its rankings?