# .tk domain name seo effect

Tags: seo, domains

This domain extension has been discussed before, but for free use.
I want to use `.tk` domain name, and I will buy it for 5 years for a fee. According to my research, the domain extension does not have much effect on SEO as before.

But to this day, I have not come across a site with a `.tk` extension in google search results.

Is it because she is bad at seo?

But I think I can get better performance from the `.com` extension with original content and a good seo configuration.

what is your opinion about it
do you think i can use?

Comment: "I have not come across a site with a `.tk` extension in google search results." - That doesn't necessarily mean anything... except that there are many more sites with an alternative TLD that have more relevant content to what you are searching for.

Comment: `tk`  is a TLD, not an "extension".

Comment: Related: [Do free TLD's affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93866/do-free-tlds-affect-seo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it's not the most popular domain extension.

Some TLDs have a terrible reputation, I mean not just old TLDs, but also some of the newly released TLDs. .bid for example, which seems to be used exclusively for spam. I even blocked it on my mail server. Nothing to lose and everything to gain, because I don't expect any legitimate mail from a .bid address, and none of my regular correspondents use it. I also blocked a couple other TLDs and I know I am not the only one doing that.

Regarding .tk I would not be surprised if it's blocked in some corporate environments at proxy level. Generally speaking any TLD that is available for free or a low registration fee is abused more.

To make an informed decision you might want to check the stats from Spamhaus:
[The 10 Most Abused Top Level Domains](https://www.spamhaus.org/statistics/tlds/). .tk is not in the top 10 nowadays but many of the featured TLDs are Freenom TLDs, that you can get for free and this is not by chance that they end up in that hall of shame.

On the other hand, registering for 5 years in advance sends a positive signal to search engines that you have long-term intentions. But if you are willing to pay, then I would encourage you to consider another TLD that carries less stigma. The question is, why register a .tk when you have plenty (hundreds) of alternatives?

Notwithstanding all the above remarks you could go ahead with your project, buy a .tk domain and you might still achieve good SEO but if mail servers do not accept your mails because they have a blanket ban on .tk, then your domain name is kinda useless. I would think about all the other practical aspects, not just the SEO.

I am not saying that this kind of blanket ban is prevalent, but there are people actively looking to ban .tk as you can see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/lvnqu4/tk_ml_gq_ga_cf_sites_might_want_to_block_these/) or [here](https://whmcs.community/topic/294306-how-to-block-free-domain-name-extensions-like-tk/). Since you are asking specifically about .tk I have the feeling you are maybe making life more difficult for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, domain extension doesn't matter but .tk is a country level domain Tokelau, a territory of New Zealand in the South Pacific. So, There may be chance that the domain doesn't well perform on other regions. I would recommend, if you just to learn then go with .tk and if you want to build a brand or a reputable blog or whatever you want then go with a Top-Level domain (.com).

Comment: `tk` is a TLD exactly at the same level than `com`. What *semantics* are attached to it is then another matter, but `tk` and `com` and over 1500 other of them are all Top Level Domains at the same level directly under the root.

Comment: "but .tk is a country level domain" - FWIW, [Google treats it like a gTLD](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites?visit_id=637802006994156440-351740481&rd=1#generic-domains). "go with a Top-Level domain (.com)" - Perhaps you meant "_global_ Top-Level domain"? (But, as mentioned, Google already does treat `.tk` as gTLD.)